# Getting maximum update depth exceeded on small screen size

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am facing a very weird error. I am using reactstrap in my Next.js application. The modal opens perfectly fine on desktop screen size. But as soon as i reduce the screen width to less than 478px I start getting this error when i toggle the modal:

```
Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.
```

Code for the modal:

```
<Modal isOpen={this.state.showAddRumourModal} toggle={this.toggleAddRumourModal.bind(this)} size="lg">
    <ModalBody>
      <div className="rumour-input">
        <label>
          <span>*</span> Rumour/Speculation <span className="extra-info">( max 400 charachters )</span>
        </label>
        <textarea maxLength="400" ref={this.rumourTextRef}>
        </textarea>
      </div>
      <div className="rumour-tags">
        <label>
          <span>*</span> Tags
        </label>
        <ReactTags tags={this.state.inputTags} suggestions={[]} handleDelete={this.handleInputTagDeletion.bind(this)}
        allowNew={true} handleAddition={this.handleInputTagAddition.bind(this)}/>
      </div>
      <button id="new-rumour-btn" onClick={this.submitRumour.bind(this)}>
        Submit
      </button>
      <style jsx>
        {`
          .rumour-input label, .rumour-tags label {
            display: block;
          }

          .rumour-input label>span, .rumour-tags label>span {
            color: red;
          }

          .rumour-tags {
            margin-top: 10px;
          }

          .rumour-input textarea {
            width: 100%;
            border: 1px solid #EAEAEA;
            border-radius: 2px;
            height: 120px;
            font-size: 14px !important;
            padding: 10px;
            font-weight: 300;
          }

          .rumour-input textarea:focus {
            outline: none;
          }

          .rumour-info-text {
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            font-size: 18px;
          }

          .extra-info {
            font-weight: 300;
            font-size: 13px;
            color: black !important;
          }

          #new-rumour-btn {
            border-radius: 2px;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-size: 14px;
            padding: 8px 27px;
            color: white;
            font-weight: 100;
            background-color: #160C35;
            cursor: pointer;
            margin-top: 20px;
          }

          @media screen and (max-width: 520px) {

            .rumour-info-text {
              font-size: 14px;
            }

            .extra-info {
              font-size: 11px;
            }

            .rumour-input label, .rumour-tags label {
              font-size: 12px;
            }

            #new-rumour-btn {
              font-size: 12px;
              padding: 4px 18px;
              margin-top: 10px;
            }
          }
        `}
      </style>
    </ModalBody>
  </Modal>
```

I toggle it using a button

```
<button id="add-btn" onClick={this.toggleAddRumourModal.bind(this)}>
   + add
</button>
```

Toggle function

```
toggleAddRumourModal() {
this.setState({
  showAddRumourModal: !this.state.showAddRumourModal,
  inputTags: []
});
```

}

From my experience and what i have googled, this error occurs when there's an infinite loop in the code, where one is performing an update state operation in the render method which again causes render.

Comment: Show your code please

Comment: @SrThompson Added the code!

Comment: Does this toggleAddRumourModal function is binded on resize event of modal?
One thing you can do is by adding breakpoint to this function and then checking the callstack to find out from where it is being called. If the breakpoint doesn't hit it then write componentDidUpdate and add debugger; statement in it and check callstack. You will get some idea from it.

Comment: @NirajRaskoti no, toggleAddRumourModal is not bound to resize event modal. This is what i have noticed: In dev environment at 478px width I get this error on page load itself, whereas if i further reduce it to 380px I dont get the error on page load, and error is for any popup not just the modal. It hits componentWillUpdate and componentDidUpdate once before giving this error. In prod environment i get this error for any screen size less 478px. What i am not getting is how can call stack be linked to screen size. I am not resizing the window that can lead to a re-render.

Comment: Can you please share the Modal component code.

Comment: Modal is included in the reactstrap library.

Comment: Are you using setState on any of the lifecycle methods? If so, please add them

Comment: No, not using setState in any life cycle methods. Even if that was the case how can that depend on the screen size.

Comment: Then maybe it's a bug in the library... because the code you're showing can't cause that error